# Need help in migrating spring code (running under OSGI using spring dm) to JDK 11

Tags: spring, osgi, aem, spring-bean, spring-dm

We have a lot of spring code written in our AEM application. We are using spring dm to run the code in osgi.

Now we would like to migrate our code to JDK 11 which requires us to migrate spring framework to 5.1 onwards. Is there a spring dm version with support springframework 5.1 onwards.

Are there any other alternative approaches to do such migration ??

regards,

Comment: Spring DM has been abondonded a very very long time ago. So no there is no version of Spring DM supporting either Java 11 or Spring 5. The project has been handed to Eclipse and led to Eclipse Blueprint and Eclipse Virgo. However neither has seen recent updates.

Comment: Is there any other way we can use spring with osgi

Comment: There is now a very interesting possibility to use OSGi Connect. OSGi Connect uses only 1 classloader while still providing a lot of OSGi features (no more dynamic updates though) and this will make Spring a lot easier to use since it is developed with 1 class loader in mind. However, this likely requires some development work since OSGi Connect is still in its infancy. You can contact me if you're interesting in pursuing this.